# Where do I get the latest IABHelper library?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, admob

I have started getting the following exception on some devices:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mycompany.iab.IabHelper.queryPurchases(Unknown Source)
at com.mycompany.iab.IabHelper.queryInventory(Unknown Source)
at com.mycompany.iab.IabHelper.queryInventory(Unknown Source)
at com.mycompany.iab.IabHelper$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

And I'm wondering if maybe I using the wrong version of the IABHelper as all the posts I find about that same exception are pretty old.

Thanks.

Comment: please check this link.http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/billing_integrate.html

Comment: That is the v2 sample and I'm using v3. I am using the iabhelper from this sample https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample but that is how I get that exception.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you probably are using the latest version. Though check the version number in the SDK manager is version 5, then perform a diff on the util folder you have in your app.  I am getting these errors too - I assume that it is user error (not calling the sample APIs correctly in some way or other). I got 2 reports today, and 1 at the end of October (2014) - not many so far...